# Malloc and class

Tags: c++, class, malloc, free

today a friend of mine sent me this code, telling me there was a mistake on it, but I'm not sure where it is. Could someone help me?

```
class MyClass
{
    int *n;
    MyClass()
    {
        n = new int;
    }

    ~MyClass()
    {
        delete n;
    }

    int main()
    {
        MyClass *c = (MyClass*)malloc(sizeof(MyClass));
        free(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: None of it is strictly a mistake; all if it is completely awful code.

Comment: The mistakeis that by using `malloc`, it won't call the MyClass's constructor..

Comment: Well, since he doesn't use any MyClass members through that pointer, using malloc there is technically okay.

Comment: What is the description of the "mistake"?  Are there compiler errors?  Are there linker errors?

Answer (score 0):

The biggest mistake is the lack of `main` function. It should be **outside the class declaration**.

Moreover, in C++ one should prefer to use `new` like this:

```
MyClass *smth=new MyClass(some_arg);
delete smth;
```

Another mistake is with the undefined variable `i` that is referred to in the constructor and destructor of the class. You should probably be using `n` instead.

To tell the truth, if I were g++ or clang or clang++ or smth like that, I'd optimize out everything as it does absolutely nothing: allocates memory and then frees it almost instantly, the constructor and destructor do nothing useful as the variable `i` *does not exist*.

Comment: Mmm yes you're right, I thought it was a writing mistake when he sent it to me. I don't know if that's the mistake he was talking to....there's another one in that code? or it was just that?

Comment: @Aseroth, yes, there is one, please see my edited answer

Comment: oooh I see, sorry the "n" and "i" thing was MY mistake, thanks I didn't know it. Looks like his mistake was the main inside MyClass. I focused in the malloc / free area and didn't see that huge mistake... Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the goal of your code, but fixing the errors it is something like this

```
#include<stdlib.h>

class  MyClass
{
   int *i;
   MyClass()
   {
       i = new int;
   }

   ~MyClass()
   {
       delete i;
   }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass *c = (MyClass*)malloc(sizeof(MyClass));
    free(c);
}
```